# How to install the correct driver in ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am new to Ubuntu so I might have missed something obvious.

I'm running a relatively old PC using a NVIDIA 750 and I have problems running streaming sites and stuff like that.  I assumed it was my driver and I went into settings which indicated that my graphics is a **AMD Bonaire** which isn't correct.

Which steps do I have to take to replace the wrong driver with the correct one?

Comment: Drivers strictly are *kernel modules*, so it is very important for GNU/Linux users to be aware of the system they are using (and what kernel is being used).  Windows kernel changes infrequently as it's not as widely used (cars, phones, tvs, etc don't run on it, and desktop users are only a tiny % of linux users) so providing your release details matter and are a starting point. If you're using a LTS release, there are two stack options (GA or HWE kernel) so being specific matters (your installation media dictates which you use unless changed).  You've provided us none of that detail.

Comment: Well, I am not very experienced with Linux given I came here and asked. I am using LTS that I installed about 2 days ago from a USB other than that I really am unaware of that amount of detail your looking for.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS was your installation media, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS was your installation media, or what release of Ubuntu you installed and used; the upgrade level (.5, .2 at the end) tells me if you opted to using a GA kernel or HWE kernel (when read with the primary release details, ie. 18.04, 20.04 bit which is the *year.month* of release, eg. 20.04 refers to the 2020-April release).   Your kernel is a key piece (`uname -r` tells me I'm using 5.10) but that can be known if full details of installation media are provided & system is fully-upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Goto "Software & Updates" app -> "Additional drivers" tab and choose your driver, Nvidia 460 seems to be the latest. Screenshot as shown: [Nvidia driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0fF9.png)

Comment: When I enter that area it says no additional drivers available.